# Continually call an API till data are available

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, json.net

An api can give me two types of response in json.

**Response 1:**

```
{
  "status": "In Progress",
  "message": "Dataset is not ready yet, try again in XXs"
}
```

**Response 2**

```
[
 {
   "data": "..." 
 },
 {
   "data": "..." 
 }
]
```

It may take the api several hours to finally have the data ready and give me the second response.

What is an optimal way to check whether the first response was generated and if so wait for some time till i call the api again till i finally get the second response?

I thought of checking whether the string starts with '{' or '[' but that does not seem to be the best way.

Comment: It's a bad design. It should be a `status` tag always.

Comment: Does that API return any status code? If not, you'll have to try and deserialize the response to see what you got. That's *not* a good way to write a long-running service though.

Comment: A common design is for the primary endpoint to return a ticket/job id that the client uses to *poll* the service for the job status. When the job is complete, the service returns the link to the results. Another option is to use WebSockets/SignalR to *tell* the client that the job is ready. At this point the service could push the data to the client, or return the URL to the results

Comment: No the response status is always 200 OK. How would i deserialize the response if the json properties are different in each response?
The API is not mine to change i can only call it.

Comment: You could try to deserialize to a `List<T>` for some `T`.  The *In Progress* response is a JSON object not a JSON array, so trying to deserialize to a collection will throw an exception.  Is that sufficient to your needs?  Kinda kludgy but it works.  Or could ***Response 2*** sometimes also be a JSON object?